# How do you use parse string in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, string, swift

An issue here to me that if i use parse string for the result of calculator program for instance,

```
4.5 * 5.0 = 22.5
```

how can I use splitting here to depart decimal part from result?

Comment: i mean if the result is 22.0 , i want just 22 not 22.0, of course if it is 22.5 , 0.5 will be there as a 22.5, but 0 of 22.0 for the result which is 22.0 or when typeing numbers 22.0 instead of 22 should not be  on right side of point ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `modf` to `extract` `decimal` `part` from result.

**Objective-C** :

```
double integral = 22.5;
double fractional = modf(integral, &integral);
NSLog(@"%f",fractional);
```

**Swift** :

```
 var integral:Double  = 22.5;
 let fractional:Double = modf(integral,&integral);
 println(fractional);
```

---

**Want only interger part from double of float**

Want only `integer` value from `double` then

```
 let integerValue:Int = Int(integral)
 println(integerValue)
```

Want only `integer` value from `float` then

```
 let integerValue:Float = Float(integral)
 println(integerValue)
```

Comment: i mean if the result is 22.0 , i want just 22 not 22.0, of course if it is 22.5 , 0.5 will be there as a 22.5, but 0 of 22.0 for the result which is 22.0 or when typeing numbers 22.0 instead of 22 should not be on right side of point ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working with strings only :

```
var str = "4.5 * 5.0 = 22.5 "

// Trim your string in order to remove whitespaces at start and end if there is any.
var trimmedStr = str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
// Split the string by " " (whitespace)
var splitStr = trimmedStr.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

// If the split was successful, retrieve the last past (your number result)
var lastPart = ""
if let result = splitStr.last {
    lastPart = result
}

// Since it's a XX.X number, split it again by "." (point)
var splitLastPart = lastPart.componentsSeparatedByString(".")

// If the split was successful, retrieve the last past (your number decimal part)
var decimal = ""
if let result = splitLastPart.last {
    decimal = result
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a test of `count` followed by `last!`, you should use `if let` syntax: `if let result = splitStr.last { lastPart = result }`.  `!` is dangerous and should only be used when there’s no practical alternative.

Comment: NP.  Also, check out `Swift.split` which is similar to `componentsSeparatedByString`: `if let result = last(split(str) { $0 == " " }), let decimal = last(split(result) {$0 == "."}) { println(decimal) }`